# C# Thread Aborting

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have used `Thread` to view a waiting form while my main form is loading in the `Load` event. But sometimes I get an `ThreadAbortException` that says "Thread was being aborted.".

Please help me to fix this problem.

Main Form Load event code:

```
WaitingForm wf;

MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            wf = new WaitingForm();
            wf.ShowDialog();
        }));
        t.Start();

        /***** Do Something *****/

        if (wf != null)
            wf.closeLoad();
        t.Abort();
}
```

WaitingForm CloseLoad Function:

```
public void closeLoad()
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        this.Close();
    });
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new form on a background thread. All UI work should be done on the UI thread. A better solution would be to open the WaitingForm on the UI thread then in the Load event of the WaitingForm start a BackgroundWorker process to do your long running operation, then close the WaitingForm.

Comment: What is `rl`? Is it the same as `wf`?

Comment: Avoid `Abort`. Period. I am not sure what you want yo do... however, you might be interested in `ManualResetEventSlim`, `Close` and `BeginInvoke`. What is `rl`? Addendum 1: Using `async/await`, `Task`, or `BackgroundWorker` are probably good ideas. Addendum 2: Ah, did you want `Application.Run`?

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but try method `Show()` without a new thread instead of `ShowDialog()` in a new thread..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Data and show a splash screen during that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489325/load-data-and-show-a-splash-screen-during-that)

Comment: @HandbagCrab It would be but its filling the datagridview that takes while to complete I can't do this action before the form open! Any solution for this?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes sorry for this mistake. It gets edit.

Comment: @Theraot My loading form progress takes while so I want to show a waitingform (included a simple gif) while the form is loading. Its filling my datagridview and it took a while for filling that. Can you give an example of async/await, Task or backgroundworker examples please?

Comment: Load the data to a `BindingList` or a `DataTable` in a background thread then once the data is loaded and the thread has complete you bind the data to the datagridview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread abort exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213343/thread-abort-exception)

Answer (score 0):

This is as compact as I could get it:

```
var waitingForm = new WaitingForm();
(new Thread (() => Application.Run(waitingForm))).Start();
HeavyWork();
waitingForm.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => waitingForm.Close()));
```

`waitingForm` will be fully responsive, operating on the anonymous thread with its own message loop. However, since it is running on another thread, we need `BeginInvoke` to close it.

We can swap this fire and forget thread with a `Task`:

```
var waitingForm = new WaitingForm();
Task.Run(() => Application.Run(waitingForm));
HeavyWork();
waitingForm.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => waitingForm.Close()));
```

---

For an alternative that uses async, consinder the following:

```
var source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

Enabled = false;
ShowWaitForm();
await HeavyWorkAsync();
Enabled = true;
source.SetResult(0);

async void ShowWaitForm()
{
    var waitingForm = new WaitingForm();
    waitingForm.Show(this);
    await source.Task;
    waitingForm.Close();
}
```

This time we are using `TaskCompletionSource` to notify that the work is finished and the `WaitingForm` can be closed, in such way that we can await it.

There is a difference that the user will percieve: The `MainForm` will be visible, and could even be responsive... we solve this by disabling it and making the `WaitingForm` a child form.

Another difference is that in this case the `WaitingForm` does not have its own message loop. However, it would still be responsive as long as you are using an async method to do your work.

Remember, it is a single thread handling both forms. This might or might not be convenient.

You can always fall back to use `Task.Run`:

```
var source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

Enabled = false;
ShowWaitForm();
await Task.Run(() => HeavyWork());
Enabled = true;
source.SetResult(0);

async void ShowWaitForm()
{
    var waitingForm = new WaitingForm();
    waitingForm.Show(this);
    await source.Task;
    waitingForm.Close();
}
```

Note that when using `Task.Run` on `HeavyWork`, `HeavyWork` is the part running in another thread. Now, it would need `BeginInvoke` to interact with the `MainForm`.

From there we can easily go to `BackgroundWorker`:

```
var source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

Enabled = false;
ShowWaitForm();
var bg = new BackgroundWorker();
bg.DoWork += (_, __) => HeavyWork();
bg.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, __) =>
{
    Enabled = true;
    source.SetResult(0);
};
bg.RunWorkerAsync();


async void ShowWaitForm()
{
    var waitingForm = new WaitingForm();
    waitingForm.Show(this);
    await source.Task;
    waitingForm.Close();
}
```